# When Uploading the new version of the App In-App and Bundle issue

Tags: app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I try to upload the new version of the app. But It rejected, because they said that it contains In-app purchase but I don't use anything for that purpose.

But the thing that I don't understand that I use the same certificate and In-App purchase is enabled for that certificate. But the first app is in the store.

And If I use the new certificate that I created with wildcard id, it looks like I can't upload it as a new version but as a new app in itunesconnect. What should I do right now, I can't upload my new version of the app?